# What is the correct way to link a favicon in IE11?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

Stackoverflow.com appears to do it this way:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d">
```

but according to the HTML5 spec

```
"shortcut icon"
```

is not a valid property and `"icon"` is.

I created a favicon.ico in gimp using a 32px by 32px layer and the same syntax as above but I used relative linking instead of `//`

Did not work for me.

Where online can I look at the spec for how IE11 implements HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

try add attribute type="image/x-icon", so look like below:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d"/>
```